# Auto call one method in several other method in a class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

Let's assume this class:

```
<?php

namespace app;

class SimpleClass {

    protected $url = '';
    protected $method = 'GET';

    public function __construct( $url, $method = 'GET' )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->prepare_something();
        // other things...
    }

    public function post()
    {
        $this->prepare_something();
        // other things...
    }

    public function patch()
    {
        $this->prepare_something();
        // other things...
    }

    public function put()
    {
        // other things...
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        // other things...
    }

    protected function prepare_something()
    {
        // preparing...
    }
```

As you can see in three methods in this class; `get, post, patch` we utilize method `preparing_something` but in methods `put, delete` we don't.

I had to repeat 3 times `$this->prepare_something();`. One time in these 3 methods `get, post, patch`. It's `3 lines` the same call in the beginning of these 3 methods.

But imagine we have 100 methods.

In 70 of them we use `$this->prepare_something();` and in 30 we don't.

Is there a way to `auto-call` these methods in these 70 methods? Without writing in every single one of these 70 methods `$this->prepare_something();`?

It's just pain and it doesn't feel right to have to call all time the same method `$this->prepare_something();` in certain methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use magic methods [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

- `__call()` - Anytime an inaccessible method is invoked `__call` will be called, so this doesn't work with public methods, you will have to rename to protected at least.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

```
public function __call($method,$args) 
{
        // if method exists
        if(method_exists($this, $method)) 
        {
            // if in list of methods where you wanna call
            if(in_array($method, array('get','post','patch')))
            {
                // call
                $this->prepare_something();
            }

            return call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$args);
        }
}
```

> **Please note :** This doesn't work with `public` method, here is results for that.

**Test Results:**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php

class Test {

       public function __call($method,$args) 
       {
         // if method exists
         if(method_exists($this, $method)) 
         {
            // if in list of methods where you wanna call
            if(in_array($method, array('get','post','patch')))
            {
                // call
                $this->prepare_something();
            }

            return call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$args);
          }
        }

    protected function prepare_something(){
        echo 'Preparing'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    // private works
    private function get(){
        echo 'get'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    // protected works
    protected function patch(){
        echo 'patch'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    // public doesn't work
    public function post(){
        echo 'post'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

    $instance = new test;

    // protected works
    $instance->prepare_something();

    // private works
    $instance->get();

    // protected works
    $instance->patch();

    // public does not work
    $instance->post();

?>
```

**Execution:**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Preparing
Preparing
get
Preparing
patch
post
```